# Test if device is Always-On/Always-Connected (AOAC) or Connected Standby is supported?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, windows-8

I am wondering if there's a way to know if Windows 8 Pro is running on an AOAC device?

And question #2, how to know if Connected Standby power state is enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code that should help: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tailoringappsfordevices/thread/eeb164a3-8ceb-4eb2-8768-4faaa7218c59/ (scroll down to the answer by 'User1024x768')

Comment: Good find. Thanks. Although there's a wrong answer marked on that thread. I'm also assuming that AOAC and Connected Standby is the same thing -- meaning that if one is supported then the other one is supported as well, right?

Comment: Yes, there is a good explanation here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wdk/thread/26629db2-6d33-427c-a767-8c857d775079/

Comment: Thanks again. Listen, a small side question. The reason I'm looking to know if Connected Standby is enabled is because it seems like wake timers are disabled if that mode is on. Do you have any experience with that?